# WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, drivers, amd-graphics, amd

put amdgpu-pro 18.50. I do not understand, it was established, but does not work? If the error is related to the kernel, then what is the reason? My kernel is the latest version 5.0.9.

```
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

and:

```
nonniks@Aze:~$ grep hybrid /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    78.398] (II) AMDGPU(0): AMDGPU DDX hybrid version: 18.50.1.418
[    78.398] (EE) AMDGPU(0): Failed to open amdgpu hybrid version
[    81.157] (II) AMDGPU(G0): AMDGPU DDX hybrid version: 18.50.1.418
[    81.157] (EE) AMDGPU(G0): Failed to open amdgpu hybrid version
```